# Eclipse: Type mismatch: cannot convert from String[] to any

Tags: javascript, eclipse

Eclipse is complaining about my JavaScript code:

[image]

As fas as I can tell, the code is working fine. What do I have to change to get rid of the warning?

Comment: It seems, that you have an extra comma at the end of your last line in `textArray[]`. Eclipse waits for another `[]`-definition, not the ending bracket for `textArray[]`.

Comment: I removed the comma, however, nothing changed.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The semantic validator (despite it's failings, like this one) actually has a lot of uses.  For instance, it can tell you when you've got a variable that's not being used anywhere (eg. because you have a typo in the variable's name).

If you don't want to see that error message, but you still want to keep semantic validation on, you can use this hack:

```
var textArray = 0 || [ ...
```

it's a little ugly, and your non-Eclipse-using co-workers may not like it, but at least it gives you a way to ditch the warning and still have the benefits of the validator.

A similar hack (if you don't like the first one, or if you're a big Douglas Crockford fan)  that will also work is:

```
var textArray;
textArray = [ ...
```

Comment: This is definitely a better option for me than turning off the semantic validation.  Agree that while there are bugs w/ the validation, it is definitely helpful in many situations. And the '0 ||' trick solves a variety of the fluky errors that I've found w/ eclipse.

Answer (score 15):

Seems to be a bug of WTP , more specifically of the JS Validator component which is by default configured to "Enable JavaScript semantic validation".

Try to turn off the semantic validation from preferences page.

Comment: Thanks, that removed the warning. But what do I loose by disabling the semantic validation?

Comment: You loose semantic validation, but it is not very useful and worse there are a lot of bugs in that feature for the moment.

Comment: It's 2017 now, how buggy is the semantic validation now to be disabled?